# Issue on summernote v0.6.16, when I click on link or picture feature, modal opens inside another modal

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, summernote

Please, see image below and you will see what I talking about.

When I click on link or picture feature of Summernote BoosTrap Editor ( v0.6.16 ) the Modal appears inside another Modal, that's weird. I don't know if I have some CSS overriding another ones or if its BUG of SummerNote.

Summernote url: http://summernote.org/#/

[image: Check out the image of Modal inside another Modal]

Thanks.

Comment: Links work fine on my copy of Summernote so I would suggest to have a look at your CSS.

Comment: What the goal of bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css, because when I remove it the link and picture works nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. In my point of view its a incompatibility between SummerNote and bootstrap-modal plugin.

In SummerNote I found code below:

```
 var tplDialog = function (className, title, body, footer) {
  return '<div class="' + className + ' modal" aria-hidden="false">' +
           '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
             '<div class="modal-content">' +
               (title ?
               '<div class="modal-header">' +
                 '<button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">&times;</button>' +
                 '<h4 class="modal-title">' + title + '</h4>' +
               '</div>' : ''
               ) +
               '<div class="modal-body">' + body + '</div>' +
               (footer ?
               '<div class="modal-footer">' + footer + '</div>' : ''
               ) +
             '</div>' +
           '</div>' +
         '</div>';
};
```

What the meaning of this, when i click on Link or Picture feature on SummerNote he calls the `.modal()` and the default behavior of this function, on Bootstrap-modal Plugin, is create a new div with class="modal-dialog". If I remove this class="modal-dialog" and try again, everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

i think you just need to enable this option

> dialogsInBody: true

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
    height: 300,
    dialogsInBody: true
});
```

Comment: then after close the `summernote's dialog`, the class `modal-open` will be removed from `body` element... how to prevent that?? i want `modal-open` class stay on `body` tag..

Answer (score 0):

As originally pointed on [this issue](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1857), Summernote´s crew has included the solution in the [documentation](https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#dialogs), which says to include the following option:

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
  dialogsInBody: true
});
```

But even so you experience a bug that freezes the underlaying modal, you can use this ugly, but handy and short workaround:

```
$('.modal.link-dialog').on('hide.bs.modal', () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($('.modal:not(.link-dialog)').hasClass('show')) {
            $('body').addClass('modal-open');
        }
    }, 0);
});
```

It basically re-add the `modal-open` class to the `body` when another modal is active.